# Is there a way to batch download assets in Portfolio Manager in Marketing Cloud's Email Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, images

Looking to move 100+ images and assets from Portfolio Manager from one BU to another BU and I don't want to manually select each item, download, and re-upload.

Is there a better way at this?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a better way for this number of images, but you could automate this using a retrieve on Portfolio to get the FileURL for each of the items in the Portfolio you're interested in and then issue a Create API call on the other MID. See retrieving here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_an_item_from_your_portfolio.htm

... and creating a Portfolio item from a URL here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/copying_an_image_from_a_website_into_the_portfolio.htm

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there's a better way other than dragging them to a local folder on your machine then using the batch import option to bring them back into the new location.

Importing into a Shared Portfolio library will allow them to be accessible by other business units as well.